# How to write subquery in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Is it possible to make following sql query in django

```
select * from (
    select * from users
) order by id
```

It is just minimal example. I have a long subquery instead of `select * from users`. But I can't  understand how insert it into subquery.

UPDATED:
Subquery from [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) doesn't suits because it build following request

```
SELECT "post"."id", (
    SELECT U0."email"
    FROM "comment" U0
    WHERE U0."post_id" = ("post"."id")
    ORDER BY U0."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1
) AS "newest_commenter_email" FROM "post"
```

and this subquery can return only one value (`.values('email')`).
Construction `select (subquery) as value from table` instead of `select value from (subquery)`

Answer (score 0):

i would use a python connector to postgreSQL - `http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/query/`, that is what i do for the mysql, thought did not try for the postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Making a subquery is essentially setting up two queries and using one query to "feed" another:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery
all_users = User.objects.all()
User.objects.annotate(the_user=Subquery(all_users.values('email')[:1]))
```

This is more or less the same as what you provided. You can get about as complicated as you'd like here but the best source to get going with subqueries is the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

Comment: So you can't use the ORM to modify the FROM clause - if you need to do that you can just drop into writing raw SQL. I can't exactly give you a better answer without something more concrete.